# How to set up vertical alignment of numbering at longtable column

Tags: pdftex, vertical-alignment, longtable, alignment

I have this longtable:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, onecolumn, oneside, final]{report}
\makeatother

\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}

\usepackage{tabto}
\newenvironment{tabs}[1]
{\TabPositions{#1}}

\usepackage{longtable}  
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{small}
    \begin{longtable}{ |p{5cm}|p{3.5cm}|p{3.6cm}| }
        \caption{\textit{State of the Art}}\\
        \hline
        \textbf{Peneliti} & \textbf{Masalah} & \textbf{Metode}\\
        \endfirsthead
        
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{\tablename~\thetable} \textit{State of the Art} (Lanjutan)}\\
        \hline
        \textbf{Peneliti} & \textbf{Masalah} & \textbf{Metode}\\
        \endhead
    
        \hline
        Chitralekha Gupta, et al.; "\textit{Perceptual Evaluation of Singing Quality}" & Melakukan evaluasi rekaman penyanyi berdasarkan 6 parameter: \textit{pitch, rhythm, voice quality, vibrato, volume, pitch dynamic range}, dan memberikan penilaian atas gabungan parameter tersebut & 
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item \textit{PRAAT} untuk pitch.
        \end{enumerate}\\
    
        \hline
        Jong Wook Kim, et al.; "\textit{CREPE: A Convolutional Representation for Pitch Estimation}". & Melakukan estimasi \textit{fundamental frequency} dari \textit{monophonic sound recording}, mengembangkan metode \textit{pitch estimation} dari algoritme pYIN. &
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item \textit{Deep convolutional neural network}.
        \end{enumerate}\\

        \hline
        Rachel M. Bittner, et al.; "\textit{Deep Salience Representations for F$_0$ Estimation in Polyphonic Music}" & Membuat model untuk mempelajari representasi unik dari \textit{pitch} dalam rekaman audio polifonik &
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item \textit{Full Convolutional Neural Network}.
        \end{enumerate}\\
    
        \hline
        Dongmei Wang, et al.; "\textit{Robust Harmonic Features for Classification-Based Pitch Estimation}" & Melakukan estimasi \textit{pitch} berdasarkan \textit{robust harmonic features} dengan membuat kandidat \textit{pitch} dan melakukan seleksi target \textit{pitch} & 
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item \textit{Neural Network}.
            \item Hidden-Markov Model.
        \end{enumerate}
        \label{tbl:StateoftheArt}\\
        \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{small}
\end{document}
```

Here is the sample output. 
[image: Output sample]

In `Metode` column, I want those items in `\begin{enumerate}` to be aligned-top like other columns. What should I modify from my longtable code?

Comment: Entirely unrelated to the issue itself: You might want to consider reducing the width of the first column while at the same time increasing the width of the second column in order to significantly reduce the amount of wasted, empty space. Left aligned instead of justified text inside of comparably narrow columns might also help to improve the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added this to the preamble

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{topsep=0pt, 
  before={\vspace{-\normalbaselineskip}\raggedright},
  leftmargin=14pt}
```

The resulting MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, onecolumn, oneside, final]{report}
\makeatother

\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}

\usepackage{tabto}
\newenvironment{tabs}[1]
{\TabPositions{#1}}

\usepackage{longtable}  
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{topsep=0pt, 
  before={\vspace{-\normalbaselineskip}\raggedright},
  leftmargin=14pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{small}
    \begin{longtable}{ |p{5cm}|p{3.5cm}|p{3.6cm}| }
        \caption{\textit{State of the Art}}\\
        \hline
        \textbf{Peneliti} & \textbf{Masalah} & \textbf{Metode}\\
        \endfirsthead
        
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{\tablename~\thetable} \textit{State of the Art} (Lanjutan)}\\
        \hline
        \textbf{Peneliti} & \textbf{Masalah} & \textbf{Metode}\\
        \endhead
    
        \hline
        Chitralekha Gupta, et al.; "\textit{Perceptual Evaluation of Singing Quality}" & Melakukan evaluasi rekaman penyanyi berdasarkan 6 parameter: \textit{pitch, rhythm, voice quality, vibrato, volume, pitch dynamic range}, dan memberikan penilaian atas gabungan parameter tersebut & 
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item \textit{PRAAT} untuk pitch.
        \end{enumerate}\\
    
        \hline
        Jong Wook Kim, et al.; "\textit{CREPE: A Convolutional Representation for Pitch Estimation}". & Melakukan estimasi \textit{fundamental frequency} dari \textit{monophonic sound recording}, mengembangkan metode \textit{pitch estimation} dari algoritme pYIN. &
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item \textit{Deep convolutional neural network}.
        \end{enumerate}\\

        \hline
        Rachel M. Bittner, et al.; "\textit{Deep Salience Representations for F$_0$ Estimation in Polyphonic Music}" & Membuat model untuk mempelajari representasi unik dari \textit{pitch} dalam rekaman audio polifonik &
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item \textit{Full Convolutional Neural Network}.
        \end{enumerate}\\
    
        \hline
        Dongmei Wang, et al.; "\textit{Robust Harmonic Features for Classification-Based Pitch Estimation}" & Melakukan estimasi \textit{pitch} berdasarkan \textit{robust harmonic features} dengan membuat kandidat \textit{pitch} dan melakukan seleksi target \textit{pitch} & 
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item \textit{Neural Network}.
            \item Hidden-Markov Model.
        \end{enumerate}
        \label{tbl:StateoftheArt}\\
        \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{small}
\end{document}
```

[image]